# How does HTML <td title> work on Mobile Phone?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have created a web application with mvc. Now I have a table and one "td" with a title:

```
<td title="@row.MsgT.FirstOrDefault()"> ... </td>
```

Now this works fine, but how will this work on mobile phone (android, IPhone, etc.)? In other words, how can you make html titles for mobile phones. Why I want to use titles is saving space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, it doesn't. The `title` attribute is for advisory information, which should be optional. Not all user agents will express it to their users.

If you want content to be available to users, put it in the text of the page.

If you want to show it conditionally, then use JavaScript to hide and show it.

Comment: great idea, tnx, I will try to make in header of table (name of column) a button, which will execute javascript for show or hide text. Something like this: <td> text <div id=nameoffunction>add-text</div>